# AngularJS model is not updating view when using input type as number

Tags: html, angularjs, validation

When I use input type as number with value attribute it didn't shows the value it the input box. But, when I change it to text it works correctly.

```
<input value="30" ng-model="project.camp_duration" min="30" max="60" id="camp_duration" name="camp_duration" type="text" placeholder="Days" class="form-control input-md" required="" autocomplete="off">

<input value="30" ng-model="project.camp_duration" min="30" max="60" id="camp_duration" name="camp_duration" type="number" placeholder="Days" class="form-control input-md" required="" autocomplete="off">
```

Above, the first one fills the text box with a value which is given.

Am I missing something or is this a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An input with type `number` has to be an `integer`.

I think your `project.camp_duration` is a String.